# Rstudio launch error, pointing to wrong location of R

Tags: r, rstudio

When Rstudio is launched from the Ubuntu launcher, I got an error

```
"R script path (/usr/lib/R) is a directory rather than a file."
```

My R is installed in

```
/usr/bin/R
```

This is quite strange as everything was fine just few hours ago and I haven't made any change to R or Rstudio.

Question is, how to make Rstudio point to the correct location of R? I'm not able to get inside the Gui, so it has to be done on command line.

```
Platform :
Rstudio 1.1.442
Ubuntu 16.04
R 3.4.4
```

EDIT : Completely reinstalled Rstudio, gotten ride of the .rstudio-desktop folder, still the same error.

I put this line in .bashrc, and I'm able to launch it from a terminal,

```
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/bin/R
```

Comment: Have you tried re-installing R?  You aren't on the latest release, so that might be a good idea anyway.

Comment: @user2554330 That may be what i have to do eventually. But I was working on it last night, and everything was fine. Why on earth would the path got altered? and got pointed to /lib/R ?

Comment: According to https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-RStudio-desktop, RStudio uses `which R` to find it.  Maybe your `PATH` has been changed?

Comment: @user2554330 My `which R` points to `/usr/bin/R`, as it should be.

Comment: @user2554330 Just reinstalled Rstudio, same issue. However, on a terminal, type rstudio, have no problem launching it.